# is possible to less float values..?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
$quantity = 20;
$product_rate = 66.79;
$total = $quantity * $product_rate;
echo $total;
```

Output is showing `1335.8000000000002`

is there possible to show 1335.8 using php..?

Comment: Looks like you want to round the value to 1 decimal place

Comment: Take a look at `number_format()` manual.

Comment: This is not a MySQL question. Please be careful about the tags you place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`number_format()`** function like this:

```
$firstNum = 1335.8000000000002;
$number = number_format($firstNum, 1, '.', '');

echo $number;
```

outputs:

```
1335.8
```

more on `number_format()` here: [http://php.net/number-format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

You can also multiply the number by 10, then use `intval()` to convert it to an `integer` (that way stripping out the decimals) and then divide by 10 like this:

```
$firstNum = 1335.8000000000002;
$number = 10 * intval($firstNum)/10;

echo $number;
```

outputs:

```
1335.8
```

**Note:** when using the methods above there will be no rounding, for rounding you would use something like this:

```
$number = round($firstNum, 1);

echo $number;
```

which in this case also outputs:

```
1335.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really use these variable values? I'm using PHP7 and the output for your given values is 1335.8. If you do a manual calculation it is the same result. It should be 1335.8. Anyway if you need to roundup the value you can use below. 
round($total,1);
Please refer the below link and you will be able to grab more details. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 0):

Because how floating point numbers work, they cannot represent every numbers exactly, so approximations are made.

The closest representation of `20` is `20`, it can represent `20` exactly, but `66.79` for instance is approximated to `66.7900000000000062527760746889`, that times `20` is `1335.800000000000125055521493778` that again cannot be represented and is approximated to `1335.80000000000018189894035459`.

Depending on how you choose to print this number, it may round different ways, in your case for some reason you decided to print 13 decimal places so it rounded to `1335.8000000000002`, but if you print only 1 or 2 decimal places it will print as `1335.8` or `1335.80`. Just be mindful about that when printing floating point numbers, you may want to specify how many decimal places are relevant to you. For that, use [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/number_format).

Example:

```
echo number_format($number, 2); // prints 2 decimal places
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply using echo `echo round($total, 1)` instead of doing `round($total)`